# Is it feasible to crack ZIP passwords?

Tags: security, zip, password-recovery

I have a piece of software I have to install on company laptops. The installer needs a serial to work properly, but I don't have it (my manager isn't here so I can't ask him). The installer tells me to ring a phone number which doesn't appear to be connected anymore.

I would download win32dasm and ollydbg and have a go at cracking the installer but I don't really have time and I haven't done it in years.

There is a zip file on the disc that looks like it contains all the program files but it is passworded. Is it feasible to crack this or will it take ages?

Answer (score 1):

As this is old software, it could be that it's using the old version of Winzip encryption - which is very crackable. A Google search will quickly turn something up.

Since Winzip v9, the encryption uses AES, which is secure.

Comment: It has XceedZip.dll in the directory so i could in theory find out the function that passes the password and see what its giving. The website for the problem software is offline as well as the phone so i think im a bit stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use some zip password recovery softwares, but it will take a long time if the password is strong. These programs generally use brute force and you will need a password dictionary for that.

Answer (score 0):

## For Linux Users

There is [Rarcrack](http://rarcrack.sourceforge.net/).

Software requirements:
* > glibc 2.4
* any POSIX compatible operating system [sorry Window$ isn't]
* pthreads
* libxml2
* and finally: 7zip, unrar, unzip

Building and installing:

Everything is very easy:

---

`tar -xjf rarcrack-VERSION.tar.bz2`
`cd rarcrack-VERSION`
you need gcc or any C compiler (edit Makefile CC=YOUR_C_COMPILER)
`make`
you must be root in next step:
`make install`

---

### Using RarCrack:

`rarcrack your_encrypted_archive.ext [--threads thread_num] [--type rar|zip|7z]`

---

Everything in [] are optional, rarcrack default crack two threads and autodetect the archive type. If the detection wrong you can specify the correct file type with the type parameter. RarCrack currently crack maximum in 12 threads.

After the cracking started RarCrack will print the current status of cracking and save it's to a status file. If you want more specific password character set, you need to run RarCrack to create the XML status file (3 sec).

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rarcrack>
   <abc>0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</abc>
 <current>uU</current>
 <good_password></good_password>
</rarcrack>
```

---

This is a sample XML file, and you see there is a character set. If you want, you can modify this file and when you start RarCrack again the program will be use new variables.

Warning: Take care when you changing this file, make sure the current password don't have characters outside the abc[character set]!