# ZIP password recovery

Tags: zip, password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [zip password crack possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/96172/zip-password-crack-possible)

I have a zip file to be password-recovered. I don't remember the password itself, but I remember what type (a capital or small letter or a digit) every symbol has.

What password recovery program supports this type of password masking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Compression-tools/ZIP-RAR-ACE-Password-Recovery.shtml

> The program is very customizable: you can set the password length, the character set to be used to generate the passwords, mask character, and a couple of other options

More to read about
http://www.softpedia.com/dyn-search.php?search_term=zip+password&x=0&y=0